# Как изменить центр view, layout и других элементов в Android Studio

Tags: android

Сталкиваюсь с проблемой, когда нужно поворачивать вьюшку относительно установленного мною центра. Иногда получается легко установить центр, если элемент простой и пропорциональный. Вручную подбиваю значения `transformPivotX` и `transformPivotY`, но на это уходит время и не совсем удобно. А если потом меняешь размер фрагмента в одинаковом процентом соотношении сторон, то снова приходится искать центр. Есть какие-то еще способы? Не такие замороченные

Comment: А если не трогать значения pivot, пробовали? По умолчанию они и так в центре вью установлены.

Comment: @eugeneek конечно, я видимо засиделся, фигню написал) я не совсем это хотел спросить, сейчас изменю вопрос

Comment: Если вы хотите установить свой pivot, то только вы знаете где он должен быть и рассчитываете его по каким-то своим методам. Не понимаю что вы ждёте получить в ответ.

Comment: ну я на игровых движках можно ручками точку просто поставить в то место, куда нужно. а здесь ты даже не видишь, где эта точка

Comment: Ну в андроид такого нет. Только кодом в рантайме либо в xml разметке.